# How to get all alphanumeric combinations with N digits on 5 positions

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

How can I get, with python, all alphanumeric combinations with `N` digits in the combinations for 5 positions.
The characters can repeat themselves.
The rest (`5-N`) characters should be letters.
Examples for what I mean:

```
Number of digits = 1 should generate:  
aygd3
2afvd
jde6a

Number of digits = 2 should generate:  
ay5d3
2af8d
jde64

Number of digits = 3 should generate:  
a15d3
26f8d
jd464

Number of digits = 4 should generate:  
315d3
26f87
9d464
```

Comment: Why do you need to have all the combinations in memory at the same time?

Comment: get `k` random digits, then `n-k` random letters. Put them in a list. `shuffle` the list and `''.join` it and you get a random word of `n` characters with `k` digits.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta: This will not get **all** combinations.

Comment: @Moberg, I need to pass over all the combinations, I can do it by incrementing by one without saving it in memory.  But, I need to pass it first by groups from 1 digit to 4 digits. So, I want to know how to get all the combinations with `N` digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive generation. 
Note that file size for 5/2 combinations is 117 MBytes
`17 576 000` values (`10^2 * 26^3 * C(5,2)`)

```
data = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'

def genld(s, maxlen, digs, digcnt):
    le = len(s)
    if (le == maxlen):
        #print(s)
        my_file.write(s + "\n")
    else:
        lo = 0 if (maxlen - le > digs - digcnt) else 26
        hi = 26 if (digcnt == digs) else 36
        for i in range(lo, hi):
            genld(s + data[i], maxlen, digs, digcnt + i // 26)

my_file = open("out.txt", "w")
genld('', 5, 2, 0)
my_file.close()
```

Comment: Nice !  Works fast.